# Getting XP-style copy and paste buttons for Windows Explorer in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I loved the Copy, Paste and Delete buttons for Windows Explorer in Windows XP. For Windows 7, Microsoft did away with those buttons and replaced them with an "Organize" menu. How can I get the buttons back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like **[ClassicShell](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7847/classicshell-adds-classic-start-menu-and-explorer-features-to-windows7/)** is for you. I will add Classic Start Menu and Explorer Features to Windows7 (including your beloved buttons :)

[image]

[Download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/classicshell/files/)

Comment: Yep, I stumbled upon this about 10 days ago. Love it. Works like a charm.

Comment: Update 2/28/2010 - It does have it's bugs though. Had to uninstall it because of conflicts with other more important software.